# onLoad="$('#link_id').trigger('click');" does not work in IE

Tags: jquery

the following code:

```
onLoad="$('#link_id').trigger('click');"
```

works in FF but does not trigger in IE. Is there a method which works both in IE and FF?

Comment: Can you give us more context? What does clicking the link do?

Comment: oops sorry, it opens up a popup alert window. I want the popup to trigger on page load instead of user having to click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you jamming this, inline, into your HTML as an event handler in a tag somewhere?

Don't do that.

Put it in an external .js file, or somewhere in a script block, after you've included the jQuery library, like this:

```
$(function() {
       $('#link_id').trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: i was using it in <body onLoad=""> event, but your recommendation is not to do that. The code, i can use it in any JS file as long as it appears after the call to jquery file correct?

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery you must do like Fausto said.

But you could try: `document.getElementById('link_id').click()`

Comment: tried that in the onLoad event but same problem. works in FF but not in IE.

Comment: if you are trying just to show a alert window in the begginning just do `alert('message')`